# How do I extract username from string?

Tags: java, regex, expression

I've been using this code I wrote some time back for my discord bot in Java:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\/setNickname ([^\\s]+)");
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(messageReceivedEvent.getMessage().getContentRaw());

        boolean foundMatch = matcher.find();
        if (foundMatch && matcher.groupCount() > 0) {
            String discordUserId = messageReceivedEvent.getAuthor().getId();
            String extractedName = matcher.group(1);
```

To change nicknames based on the text a user enters into the channel in the format of:
`[HH:MM:SS] /setNickname Bill`

This code works correctly. However, I am now wanting to change it, but I cannot seem to get the regex pattern to work for a new format of the message. It is always a message the player has to enter with a timestamp, so the entry would be :
 `[HH:MM:SS] Bill 4cYaUTKzT2odRf2`

At some point I plan to build on this and make it a variable so eliminating before and after the second space seems like the most logical choice, but I am struggling with it.

The input would be: `[HH:MM:SS] Bill 4cYaUTKzT2odRf2`

The output should be just: `Bill`

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: What is the output you want?

Comment: can you provide an input output example

Comment: I am sorry, I spaced the output. The output should be literally just Bill. I think that this would be close? .*(]\s)(.*)(\s).* with a matcher.group(2) but I'm not sure.

Comment: How about: `^\[[0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]\] (\S+)` See [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/chMxMU/1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this REGEX `([A-Z:\\[\\]]+\\s)([A-Za-z]+)(\\s[0-9A-Za-z]+)`

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String input = "[HH:MM:SS] Bill 4cYaUTKzT2odRf2";
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("([A-Z:\\[\\]]+\\s)([A-Za-z]+)(\\s[0-9A-Za-z]+)");
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(input);
        if (matcher.find()) {
            System.out.println(matcher.group(2));
        }
    }
```

, output

```
Bill
```

, or REGEX `([0-9:\\[\\]]+\\s)([A-Za-z]+)(\\s[0-9A-Za-z]+)`

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String input = "[10:30:10] Bill 4cYaUTKzT2odRf2";
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("([0-9:\\[\\]]+\\s)([A-Za-z]+)(\\s[0-9A-Za-z]+)");
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(input);
        if (matcher.find()) {
            System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
            System.out.println(matcher.group(2));
            System.out.println(matcher.group(3));
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks this method worked just fine. I also appreciated being able to see the groups while executing the code before-hand. Messing with Discord bots in real time is a pain.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe there's more variability in the input than you've indicated, but wouldn't this work:

```
String input = "[HH:MM:SS] Bill 4cYaUTKzT2odRf2";
String extractedName = input.replaceAll(".+\\s([A-Za-z]+)\\s.+", "$1");
System.out.println(extractedName);
```

Output:

```
Bill
```

Comment: This method also worked, I did upvote but I do not have 15 reputation yet, so it doesn't show. Thank you for your reply and thought process. I may need to utilize this as things progress in the code. The ability to assign the string to a variable was not something I had considered.